# Implementing merge-sort in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the merge-sort algorithm in Python 3. Here's the function that implements the merge part of the algorithm:

```
def Merge(A,p,q,r):
n1 = q - p + 1
n2 = r - q

#We first populate two lists that contain the sorted subsequences A[p,...,q] and A[q+1,...,r]
L = []
R = []

for index in range(n1):
    L.append(A[index + p])

for index in range(n2):
    R.append(A[index + q + 1])

#We now overwrite the A[p,..,q,...r] section of the list by comparing the 'top-most'
#elements in the lists l and R and putting the smaller element in the corresponding
#entry in A. If one of the list is fully exposed/no longer available, we simply put the 
#remaining list's elements in the corresponding positions in A.

i = 0
j = 0

for k in range(r - p + 1 ):

    if i > n1-1:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j = j + 1

    elif j > n2-1:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i = i + 1

    elif L[i] < R[j]:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i = i + 1

    else:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j = j + 1 

return A
```

I have tested this function and it runs fine: as long as the subarrays A[p,q] and A[q+1,r] are sorted, the whole array A[p,r] will be sorted correctly. I now try and implement a divide and conquer approach to merge a large enough list.

```
import math

def Merge_Sort(A,p,r):

if p == r:

    return A

if p < r:

    q = math.floor((p+r)/2)
    Merge_Sort(A,p,q)
    Merge_Sort(A,q+1,r)
    Merged_List = Merge(A,p,q,r)

return Merged_List
```

But I get erroneous answers when I run it. Here's an example:

```
#We now analyze the merge sort algorithm.
A = [1,7,9,3]
B = Merge_Sort(A,0,3)
print(B)
```

The output is

```
[3, 9, 3, 9]
```

I am probably making some obvious/stupid mistake in the implementation of the divide and conquer bit. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the assignments to `A[k]`. They should be changed to assignments to `A[p+k]`.

Note that `L` and `R` can be defined using the following syntax (no explicit loop):

```
L = A[p:q+1]
R = A[q+1:r+1]
```

To be consistent with how native functions work in Python (e.g. `list.extend`), your two functions should *not* return the list. They *mutate* the list that you pass as argument, and so to avoid confusion, it is better not to return it: it could make users of your code think that the function has no side effects.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much. I didn’t realise I changed the format of how the range function from p to r was implemented. I was confused if I had misimplemented the recursive portion of the code - all overwriting was done on the initial list so I thought I may have made some implementation mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Merge Sort Algorithm, We first divide the array into two parts recursively, then sort each part and merge them recursively.So, Its a divide and conquer algorithm.

```
MergeSort(arr[], l,  r)
If r > l
     1. Find the middle point to divide the array into two halves:  
             middle m = (l+r)/2
     2. Call mergeSort for first half:   
             Call mergeSort(arr, l, m)
     3. Call mergeSort for second half:
             Call mergeSort(arr, m+1, r)
     4. Merge the two halves sorted in step 2 and 3:
             Call merge(arr, l, m, r)
```

I think your code have problem in the merge function.Where you should assign the elements of array L and array R. Your starting index is p, Therefore you should assign L[i] and R[i] to A[p+k] instead of A[k].
If you still have doubts regarding merge sort refer to [Merge Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/).
hope this solves all your queries.
Thanks